# Auxotrophic complementation test with yeast

Tags: yeast

If auxotrophic strains grow on minimal media do they complement each other or not?  Also, is complementation the same thing as complementing each other?

Answer (score 2):

If the yeast strain A is auxotrophic for AA 1 and the yeast strain B is auxotrophic for AA 2, neither would be able to grow in minimal medium by itself. But combined they complement the lack of AA1 in strain A by strain B and vice versa. That is metabolic complementation.